# Minimize $x y$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$ by linear independence constraint qualification

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

I'm trying to solve this problem by KKT

> $$\begin{align*}
> \text{min} & \quad x y \\
> \text{s.t} & \quad x^2 + y^2 \le 1
> \end{align*}$$

One of the regularity conditions is **linear independence constraint constraint** qualification - LICQ, which is

> The gradients of the active inequality constraints and the gradients of the equality constraints are linearly independent at $x^{*}$.

Could you please verify if I correctly apply the KKT's theorem? Thank you so much for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

Let $f(x,y) = x y$, $g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$, and $\mathcal K= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid g(x,y) \le 0\}$. Because $\mathcal K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, the problem has a solution.

Moreover, $\nabla f (x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} y \\ x \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and $\nabla g (x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ \end{pmatrix}$. Consider the system $$\begin{cases}
g(x,y) &= 0\\
\mu \nabla g (x,y) &= 0\\
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2 &= 1\\
\mu \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ \end{pmatrix} &= 0\\
\end{cases}
\implies \mu =0$$

Hence **LICQ** is satisfied. Consider the system

$$\begin{cases}
\mu \ge 0 \\
\mu g(x,y)=0 \\
\nabla f (x,y)+\mu \nabla g (x,y) =0
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
\mu \ge 0 \\
\mu (x^2+y^2-1)=0 \\
 \begin{pmatrix} y \\ x \\ \end{pmatrix} + \mu \begin{pmatrix} 2x \\ 2y \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
\mu \ge 0 \\
\mu (x^2+y^2-1)=0 \\
2x \mu = -y \\
2y \mu = -x
\end{cases}$$

Solving this system, we get $$(\mu,x,y) \in \left  \{(0,0,0), \left (1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ), \left (1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ), \left (-1,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ), \left (1,\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right )  \right \}$$

Consequently, $f (0,0) = 0$, $f \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ) = \frac{1}{2}$, $f \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ) = \frac{-1}{2}$, $f \left (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $f \left (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ) = \frac{-1}{2}$.

Hence the solution to the problem is $$\left\{\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ),\left (\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \right ) \right\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: You can also consider $$f(x,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})=x\times(\pm\sqrt{1-x^2})$$

Comment: My goal is to apply KKT's theorem :((